# What hardware do the Google servers use?

Tags: hardware, google

What kind of hardware does Google use?

- Exclusively Intel processors? Always?
- Xeons, Duos, or Quads?
- Intel chipsets?
- motherboards - Intel, Gigabyte, MSI?
- What kind and build of RAM?
- What physical memory configuration (single large capacity modules or multiple smaller capacity modules)?
- What brand of HDD (I know they used to buy almost all the brands - from their disk failure report)?
- Were they able to implement a single voltage power supply for their servers (like they had been pushing for a long time to Intel)?

Any other trivia you have or would like to share?

Comment: This would fit better on Serverfault.com or SuperUser.com

Comment: People shouldn't move conversations from StackOverflow or ServerFault to SuperUser.com while it's still in better.  It's fracking annoying to be posting a decent answer to something in one side, and then bam, it's closed and locked up in a site I can't access.  What if the author himself doesn't have access to the site?

Comment: @darthcoder ServerFault is no longer password protected. Try clearing your cookies etc. and accessing it - it'll let you right in.

Answer (score 12):

Lots of these:

[Servers](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-10209580-92.html)

Comment: this was pretty much the defining article for me

Comment: the link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Google platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform).

Comment: mmmm.... Server Pr0n

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty neat discription.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-10209580-92.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want commercially available hardware that's very similar to what Google does (DC power supplies, stripped down systems, ultra high density) then check out SGI/Rackable's [Cloud Rack](http://www.rackable.com/products/cloudrack.aspx?nid=servers_6) product line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting Google themselves? Seems to me anything else is probably just guesswork.

Comment: Google are notoriously silent about their data centers or configurations, hence all the guesswork ;)